How do I populate intl-tel-input fields with turbo_stream?
I already have the number saved in my database, using a turbo_stream file and using the turbo_power library I need to change the empty value to the number I have in my database (example: +5561984568754).
The value is changed, but the flag is not selected automatically, as if I had filled it in manually.
In my turbo_stream (haml):
= turbo_stream.set_value '#phone_field', @contact.phone_number 

In my html (haml):
= form.text_field :phone_field, class: 'form__control', data: { phone_number_target: 'input' }

In my javascript (stimulus):
import {Controller} from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import intlTelInput from 'intl-tel-input';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ['input']

  connect() {
    this.iti = intlTelInput(this.inputTarget, {
      utilsScript: "/assets/utils.js",
      strictMode: true,
      countryOrder: ["BR", "PT", "ST", "CV", "LU", "FR", "GB"]
    });


    const formElement = this.inputTarget.closest("form");

    if (formElement) {
      formElement.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        this.inputTarget.value = this.iti.getNumber();
      });
    }
  }
}


What flag do you want to be set?
